# Missing \endcsname inserted in overleaf project

Tags: overleaf

I was working on my thesis using a template and suddenly I can't compile my project anymore. I am still able to compile it in the "fast" mode, but when I switch to the normal, I receive the below error.

Can you help me with that? I need to submit my thesis in the upcoming days, and I can't risk losing all that work.

The line the error is mentioning to is just \begin{document}, there is nothing else.

> Compile Error. Sorry, your LaTeX code couldn't compile for some
> reason. Please check the errors below for details, or view the raw
> log.  LatexDiss/Dissertation/diss.tex, line 25
>
> Missing \endcsname inserted.
>
> \relax  l.25 \begin{document}
>                       The control sequence marked  should not appear between \csname and \endcsname. 
> LatexDiss/Dissertation/diss.tex, line 25
>
> Extra \endcsname.
>
> \check@bm@number ...0\else \csname B_#1\endcsname
> \fi  l.25 \begin{document}
> I'm ignoring this, since I wasn't doing a \csname.  LatexDiss/Dissertation/diss.tex, line 25
>
> Missing \endcsname inserted.
>
> \endgroup  l.25 \begin{document}
>                       The control sequence marked  should not appear between \csname and \endcsname. 
> LatexDiss/Dissertation/diss.tex, line 25
>
> Use of \B_ doesn't match its definition.
>
> \endgroup
> l.25 \begin{document}
> If you say, e.g., `\def\a1{...}', then you must always put` 1' after `\a', since control sequence names are made up of
> letters only. The macro here has not been followed by the required
> stuff, so I'm ignoring it.  LatexDiss/Dissertation/diss.tex, line 25
>
> Missing number, treated as zero.
>
> \endcsname  l.25 \begin{document}
>                       A number should have been here; I inserted `0'. (If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number, look up `weird
> error' in the index to The TeXbook.)  LatexDiss/Dissertation/diss.tex,
> line 25
>
> Missing { inserted.
>
> Check that your $'s match around math expressions. If they do, then
> you've probably used a symbol in normal text that needs to be in math
> mode. Symbols such as subscripts ( _ ), integrals ( \int ), Greek
> letters ( \alpha, \beta, \delta ), and modifiers (\vec{x}, \tilde{x} )
> must be written in math mode. See the full list here.If you intended
> to use mathematics mode, then use $ … $ for 'inline math mode', $$ …
> $$ for 'display math mode' or alternatively \begin{math} … \end{math}.
> Learn more
>
> \endcsname  l.25 \begin{document}
>                       A left brace was mandatory here, so I've put one in. You might want to delete and/or insert some corrections so that I
> will find a matching right brace soon. (If you're confused by all
> this, try typing `I}' now.)  LatexDiss/Dissertation/diss.tex, line 25
>
> Extra \else.
>
> \ReadBookmarks ...fx \WriteBookmarks \relax \else
> \if@filesw \newwrite @out... l.25 \begin{document}
> I'm ignoring this; it doesn't match any \if.  LatexDiss/Dissertation/diss.tex, line 25
>
> Undefined control sequence.
>
> The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used.
> Check that the command is spelled correctly. If the command is part of
> a package, make sure you have included the package in your preamble
> using \usepackage{...}.  Learn more
>
> @outlinefile
> l.25 \begin{document}
> The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have misspelled it
> (e.g., `\hobx'), type` I' and the correct spelling (e.g., `I\hbox').
> Otherwise just continue, and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
> LatexDiss/Dissertation/diss.tex, line 25
>
> Undefined control sequence.
>
> The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used.
> Check that the command is spelled correctly. If the command is part of
> a package, make sure you have included the package in your preamble
> using \usepackage{...}.  Learn more
>
> ... \immediate \closeout @outlinefile
> \ReFiCh@Check {}\x {\jobna... l.25 \begin{document}
> The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have misspelled it
> (e.g., `\hobx'), type` I' and the correct spelling (e.g., `I\hbox').
> Otherwise just continue, and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
> LatexDiss/Dissertation/diss.tex, line 25
>
> Undefined control sequence.
>
> The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used.
> Check that the command is spelled correctly. If the command is part of
> a package, make sure you have included the package in your preamble
> using \usepackage{...}.  Learn more
>
> \x
> l.25 \begin{document}
> The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have misspelled it
> (e.g., `\hobx'), type` I' and the correct spelling (e.g., `I\hbox').
> Otherwise just continue, and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
> LatexDiss/Dissertation/diss.tex, line 25
>
> Undefined control sequence.
>
> The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used.
> Check that the command is spelled correctly. If the command is part of
> a package, make sure you have included the package in your preamble
> using \usepackage{...}.  Learn more
>
> ...Ch@0 \MessageBreak After: \space \x
> @gobble  l.25 \begin{document}
> The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have misspelled it
> (e.g., `\hobx'), type` I' and the correct spelling (e.g., `I\hbox').
> Otherwise just continue, and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
> LatexDiss/Dissertation/diss.tex, line 25
>
> Undefined control sequence.
>
> The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used.
> Check that the command is spelled correctly. If the command is part of
> a package, make sure you have included the package in your preamble
> using \usepackage{...}.  Learn more
>
> \ReadBookmarks ...mmediate \openout @outlinefile
> =\jobname .out\relax \ifHy... l.25 \begin{document}
> The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have misspelled it
> (e.g., `\hobx'), type` I' and the correct spelling (e.g., `I\hbox').
> Otherwise just continue, and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
> LatexDiss/Dissertation/diss.tex, line 25
>
> Extra \fi.
>
> \ReadBookmarks ... {\relax }\fi \fi \fi
> l.25 \begin{document}
> I'm ignoring this; it doesn't match any \if.  LatexDiss/Dissertation/diss.tex, line 25
>
> Extra \fi.
>
> \Hy@AtBeginDocumentHook ...per \ReadBookmarks \fi
> \Hy@pdfstringtrue \PDF@Set... l.25 \begin{document}
> I'm ignoring this; it doesn't match any \if.  LatexDiss/Dissertation/diss.tex
>
> Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 25.
>
> \fi   diss.tex
>              The file ended while I was skipping conditional text. This kind of error happens when you say `\if...' and forget the
> matching `\fi'. I've inserted a `\fi'; this might work.
>
> ! Emergency stop. <*> diss.tex
>
> *** (job aborted, no legal \end found)
>
> Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:  14541 strings out of
> 493013  232747 string characters out of 6135683  674156 words of
> memory out of 5000000  17810 multiletter control sequences out of
> 15000+600000  4702 words of font info for 16 fonts, out of 8000000 for
> 9000  1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191  43i,1n,45p,1143b,716s
> stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s !  ==> Fatal
> error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
>
> BibTeX /compile/output.bcf is malformed, last biblatex run probably
> failed. Deleted /compile/output.bbl

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: looks as if you something bad in some section or other heading argument. Move \end{document} until you find the problematic entry.

Comment: Hi Ulrike, 

what do you mean by "Move \end{document}? I have 8 different folders representing each chapter in my thesis.

For each chapter, I dont have end doument, I have it only once in the diss file where it is showing the error. 

I tried to remove chapters and compile one by one, but that didnt help.